# django-admin.py startproject mysite; results in an empty directory

Tags: python, django

django version 1.7b1
ubuntu 12 LTS
python3.2

The command:
django-admin.py startproject mysite

results in an empty directory, but in reality it should put the following files in mysite/:

```
manage.py


mysite/

    __init__.py

    settings.py

    urls.py

    wsgi.py
```

ideas?

Comment: Has it thrown any errors? What if you try with the latest stable 1.6.2 version?

Comment: No errors, and i would try it with that version but the docs aren't written for python 3 for that version :(. I spent about 2 days learning python 3 was hoping to apply it with django. Why the hell am i being downvoted :(

Comment: What is the output of `django-admin.py --version`?

Comment: 1.7b1 (i'm not just saying that i actually punched in the command)

Comment: Shouldn't happen? Are you sure you are doing `ls` in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
django-admin startproject myproject

**no .py**!

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin-py